# Function called with no arguments doesn't give error

Tags: c++, g++

I was coding some problem when i observed this. Since Functions are supposed to be a group of statements that is given a name, which can be called from some point of the program. Consider a simple program that gives the absolute value of an integer :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int getAbsolute(int x) {
  return x > 0 ? x : -1*x;
}

int main() {
  vector<int> arr;

  for(int i = -5; i < 5; i++) 
    arr.push_back(i);

  for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    cout << "abs(" << arr[i] << ") : "
         << getAbsolute << endl;
  }
}
```

When i run this program :

```
rohan@~/Dropbox/cprog/demos : $ g++ testFunction.cpp 
rohan@~/Dropbox/cprog/demos : $ ./a.out
abs(-5) : 1
abs(-4) : 1
abs(-3) : 1
abs(-2) : 1
abs(-1) : 1
abs(0) : 1
abs(1) : 1
abs(2) : 1
abs(3) : 1
abs(4) : 1
rohan@~/Dropbox/cprog/demos : $
```

My question is, Why doesn't this program give me error that i'm supposed to call with arguments, Is something wrong with my g++(-v 4.8.5)? And why does this program output's 1 on each call? Or am i missing something here? I'm really confused.

Comment: You are not calling the function but just using its address

Comment: What you wanted to try was `getAbsolute()`

Comment: You mean 1 is the value dereferenced from the getAbsolute memory address? But how does compiler decide how far it has to read since function's address is just a raw pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
cout << "abs(" << arr[i] << ") : "
         << getAbsolute << endl;
```

is correct. The function designator `getAbsolute` implicitly is converted to the function pointer `int (*)( int )` according to the function declaration

```
int getAbsolute(int x);
```

and this pointer is outputted using the following operator `operator <<`

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(bool n);
```

and you get the result like this

```
abs(-5) : 1
```

because the function pointer is unequal to zero and this operator is the best overloaded operator `operator <<` for a function pointer of such type.

Comment: This question is duplicate. You better close it than answering :)